# Tensorflow range vs. labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, label, model-fitting

Tensorflow is killing me, pls help :) I found some answers here regarding the issue I have but they are useless... I cannot understand why I get this message:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Received a label value of 3 which is outside the valid range of [0, 3).  Label values: 2 3 3 1 2 1 1 3 1 1 1 2 3 3 1 1 1 3 1 3 2 3 1 2 1 3 2 1 2 2 2 3
     [[node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits (defined at <ipython-input-68-069e54b769de>:2) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_47373]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

I have three ouptut labels but error suggest 233121... goes beyond three... Why? Funny, when I change the number of labels in the last dense layer to 4, everything works. But I do not want 4 classes because prediction matrix returns 4 columns with probabilities.

My simple network looks like this:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(len(word_index) + 1,
                     EMBEDDING_DIMENSION))
model.add(SpatialDropout1D(0.3))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(EMBEDDING_DIMENSION)))
model.add(Dense(EMBEDDING_DIMENSION, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.8))

model.add(Dense(EMBEDDING_DIMENSION, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.8))

model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
```

What do I make wrong? I have the latest tf 2.3. I only change data input as I replicate example that works with original data... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Your labels should start at 0. That is, the values in the message would be `[1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, ...]`. In general, when you have `n` classes, encode labels as integers between `0` and `n-1`. Since you did not include the code where you define the labels, unfortunately I cannot include a code example for that.

Comment: It did not work. I recoded my labels to 0,1,2 but error still exists... In the example I replicate (this one works) labels are textual [thr, bfg, tdf] and initially my labels were textual too [a,b,c,]. Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: I think I found the solution. In the embedding layer shape needs to defined by three args: model.add(Embedding(VOCAB_SIZE, EMBEDDING_DIM, input_length=X.shape[1])) What is critical, input_length needs to matched with X.shape[1] right value!!! It works in my case (mutilabel classification, NLP).